# Failed to attach: :3333: Operation timed out. (from target-select remote :3333) Issue to debug riscV-WCH device ch32v307 in VsCode 1.68 in Mac Os

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb, embedded, openocd

I stay trying this: https://nc-pin.com/index.php/category/wch/ch32v-series/ch32v307/
**Debugging CH32V307V with Visual Studio Code on macOS**

The part more confuse is this: *“I saved a workspace of Visual Studio Code into the ch32v307/EVT/EXAM/GPIO/GPIO_Toggle/User directory and added this directory to the workspace also±”*

But I can create a lauch.json with **workspace(3)** and **GDB(4)**

After I mounted with hdid, mount and export PATH, etc…

But in Final I have issue: **Failed to attach: :3333: Operation timed out. (from target-select remote :3333)**

**Note:**

1. I don't know why but in tutorial not talk about task.json. When I see a message about this on the screen(Because I have "preLaunchTask": "run_openocd" in launch.json) I click on debug anyway

**Will I need task.json to resolve my issue?**

2. Is this link I have source codes that I am using and **images with
   issue**  called images: captura de tela 2022-07-04

https://github.com/neuberfran/ch32v307

How can I solve?

Pls

edited in 06-11-2022. The solution for this issue is use wch-link version 2.3(Not 2.4 upstream today). But so far, it has not been possible to Downgrade from 2.4 to 2.3. Look wehnelt comment in this post:https://www.reddit.com/r/embedded/comments/ut94i3/the_riscv_mcu_ch32v307_is_a_bad_boy/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the need to update in wch-link v2.4 (for Mac OS and Ubuntu), this answer (2022-07-23) comes to complement the tutorial: https://nc-pin.com/index.php/category/wch/ch32v-series/ch32v307/

1. Open Mac Os terminal

1.1) https://github.com/neuberfran/openocd
(**openocd** it's working ok)

1.2) go to /Users/username/csfs/openocd:
./openocd -f wch-riscv.cfg -c init -c halt -c "flash erase_sector wch_riscv 0 last" -c exit

2. git clone https://github.com/neuberfran/GPIO_Toggle
   2.1) go to Finder ->  GPIO_Toggle/User ->  double click in GPIO_Toggle.code-workspace
3. in VsCode go to Terminal:
   export PATH="$HOME/csfs/x-tools/riscv32-unknown-elf/bin:$HOME/csfs/openocd:$PATH"

note.:
You have probably already run:
hdid -nomount csfs.sparseimage

mount -t hfs /dev/diskXs2 csfs

3.1) mark line 56 in main.c File (debug breakpoint)

4. Press F5 ...(If a warning screen appears, click **Debug Anyway**). Next Debug Console will automatically open and debugger will stop at line 56. Click F5 agin (Continue button, up there in VsCode). **The Led will blink. Click F6 to stop and F5 to continue.**
5. Remove And Reconnect the USB-C cables from the board. Go to the Mac OS terminal that you open in Step nr.: 1.2. Execute again Step 1.2. Go to Step 4.